# How to switch views via buttons in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am a novice to android programming and I am trying to create a simple button that switches the view from activity_main_menu.xml to info_menu.xml on the click of a button. Here is the source and XML, respectively.

MainMenu.java

```
package us.wi.k12.cadottschools;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainMenu extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        final Button infoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.InfoButton);

        infoButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        setContentView(R.layout.info_menu);
                    };
                });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

avtivity_main_menu.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >
<Button android:id="@+id/CalendarButton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/calendar_button" />
<Button android:id="@+id/InfoButton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/info_button" />
<Button android:id="@+id/ContactButton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/contact_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Both run without any errors thrown, but when I click on the button InfoButton, nothing happens.

Comment: You have an extra `;` after your `}` for the `onClick()`. Also, you should create a separate `Activity` and call `setContentView()` with the appropriate `layout` there and start that `Activity` with an `Intent` in the `onClick()`. Calling `setContentView()` multiple times in one `Activity` usually isn't a good idea

Comment: +1 If I could accept this as the answer to my problem, I would @codeMagic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Converting comment to answer**

You have an extra `;` after your `}` for the `onClick()`. So it should look like

```
        infoButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                setContentView(R.layout.info_menu);
            }  // sholdn't be one here since its closing a method
        });
```

Its generally not good practice to call `setContentView()` multiple times in one `Activity`. This will lead to problems because any `View`s in your original `layout` will be `null`. It is better to start a new `Activity` (or use `Fragment`s) inside your `onClick()`. Then in your new `Activity` set the `layout` here (`info_menu.xml`) in `setContentView()` of your new `Activity`.

So then your `onClick()` would look something like

```
 infoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
 {   
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
           Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), NextActivityName.class);
           startActivity(i);
     }  
});
```

[Intent Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

[Activity Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

Answer (score 1):

Though `setcontentView()` can be called multiple times, it is not recommended.

Start a new activity or use [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) or ViewSwitcher are better solutions.

BTW, if setcontentview() is called again, all objects should be `find` again by using `view.findviewbyid()`.

Answer (score 0):

This link should be helpful if you are okay with starting a new activity to swap the views: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

If you are trying to swap the views without starting a new activity, combine both your layout xml files into a single file. Then set the visibility of the view you want set before button press to View.VISIBLE and the view you don't want to see before button press to View.GONE. Then once you press the button, set the view you want to see to View.VISIBLE and the one you don't want to see to View.GONE.

If you want a code sample let me know!

Answer (score 0):

`Fragment` and `ViewPager` may be what you want. and you could use an `FrameLayout` and multi `*Layout` in it, then change visibility (not really change the view, but no different to users)

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way to switch to new view is by starting a new activity. But if you want to change existing view by clicking on button. You can use LayoutInflater.

Refer
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-dynamic-layout-using-xml-add.html
https://justanapplication.wordpress.com/tag/android-view-layoutinflater/

Answer (score 0):

You can only setContent for once within an Activity.If you want to switch views,you can try fragment:
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
    }

    private PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment() {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_menu, container, false);
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```